# Decide evaluation points for a function using `\addplot`

Tags: pgfplots, axis

I'm plotting a function on a log scale in `pgfplots`.
I was just wondering if there is a way to indicate onto which points I'd like the function to be evaluated.

Specifically, in my case, I'm plotting something between `2` and `256` on a `log2` scale. Therefore, I'd like to have the markers at x-values corresponding to powers of two (i.e. `2, 4, 8, 16` etc).

At the moment, the result assign the samples according to a linear scale.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\*
\begin{axis}[
%
    xmode=log,
    log ticks with fixed point,
    log basis x={2},
    xmin=2, xmax=256,
    xminorticks=true, yminorticks=true,    
    ytick={0,200,...,800},
    xtick = {2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256},
    xticklabel style={text width=2em,align=center},     
    xmajorgrids,  xminorgrids,
    ymajorgrids,  yminorgrids,
]

\addplot [color=black,mark=pentagon*,domain=2:256,samples=10,variable=\R]
(\R, {3*\R + 2});
\end{axis}
%*/
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Of course, I could think of calculating the function in the desired points in an external program (e.g. Matlab) and then exporting to `TikZ`, but I'd rather have an all-TikZ solution, in case I want to change something without needing to go through an external program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `samples at` key, i.e.

```
\addplot [color=black,mark=pentagon*,samples at={2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256},variable=\R] (\R, {3*\R + 2});
```

You can also then say `xtick=data` in the `axis` options, to avoid having to specify the numbers twice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
%
    xmode=log,
    log ticks with fixed point,
    log basis x={2},
    xmin=2, xmax=256,
    xminorticks=true, yminorticks=true,    
    ytick={0,200,...,800},
    xtick = data,
    xticklabel style={text width=2em,align=center},     
    xmajorgrids,  xminorgrids,
    ymajorgrids,  yminorgrids,
]

\addplot [color=black,mark=pentagon*,samples at={2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256},variable=\R] (\R, {3*\R + 2});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So simple, yet I couldn't find the answer on my own :)
Thanks for the speed of the reply!